# How do I rotate an image using google docs api in google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am using Google Scripts to do a mail-merge like creation of the document.  I need to be able to insert to images that are created dynamically.  One is as-is and the other needs to be rotated 90-degrees.

I have been able to get the image after appending to the document, but the image attributes do not provide for setting the angle.  In reviewing the body of the document there is an area I could insert the angle setting.  In the JSON provided, it is the imageProperties. If I could get to it and add **"angle": number** it should rotate the image.

```
"revisionId": "AOV_f49iY5wC2Fm-Bm8uhcx6XmmXfNqs_hK-5Ac3PXlhXV5BiFYD4u-4beWO9WdQQCfYmy3nfjODTRrDcdWNIg",
  "suggestionsViewMode": "SUGGESTIONS_INLINE",
  "inlineObjects": {
    "kix.4aowmksp4phx": {
      "objectId": "kix.4aowmksp4phx",
      "inlineObjectProperties": {
        "embeddedObject": {
          "imageProperties": {
            "contentUri":
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/aBdOBxBXK_0uaz1b9vJS",
            "sourceUri": "http://barcodes4.me/barcode/c39/undefined.png?height=100",
            "cropProperties": {}
------->>>  "angle": 1.567
          },
          "embeddedObjectBorder": {
...
```

Any ideas on how to set the imageProperties.angle value?

Comment: Apparently the `angle` property is currently read-only. The Docs API does not seem to provide a way to set that property.

Comment: How are you retrieving the images?

Comment: The images are coming from a web URL.  I convert them to blob and appendInlineImage.  After this I want to rotate the image.

Comment: After reviewing the documentation, I agree with Dimu, there does not seem to be a way to alter the angle property, I tried using the `batchUpdate` method ([here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)) but angle was not even an option, I would suggest opening a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)

Comment: Since a feature request does not appear to have been opened for this, I have opened one here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147968327